# What does it mean for ReadFile to be "completing asynchronously", and why is it an error?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, asynchronous, serial-port

I'm (synchronously) reading serial input in Windows using `ReadFile()`, but instead of waiting for the serial port to have input then returning that as I thought it should, `ReadFile()` instead returns immediately with a value of `FALSE`, and a `GetLastError()` of 0. (Yes, I'm certain I have the right error code and am not making syscalls in between).

The [ReadFile() documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that when the function "is completing asynchronously, the return value is zero (FALSE)." How is it that a synchronous read can be completing asychronously? Why would this be an error? It's worth noting that the data read is garbage data, as one might expect.

More generally, how can I force `ReadFile()` to behave like a simple synchronous read of a serial port, or at least behave something like the UNIX `read()`?

**Edit:** Here is some source code:

```
HANDLE my_connect(char *port_name)
{
    DCB dcb;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    HANDLE hdl = CreateFile(port_name,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            0);

    GetCommState(port_name, &dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = 115200;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if(SetCommState(hdl, &dcb) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetCommState failed with error code %d.\n",
                GetLastError());
        return (HANDLE) -1;
    }

    /* TODO: Set a variable timeout. */
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 5000; /* wait 5s for input */
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 5000;
    if(SetCommTimeouts(hdl, &timeouts) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SetCommTimeouts failed with error code %d.\n",
                GetLastError());
        return (HANDLE) -1;
    }

    return hdl;
}

int my_disconnect(HANDLE hdl)
{
    return CloseHandle(hdl);
}

int my_send(HANDLE hdl, char *cmd)
{
    DWORD nb = 0;
    if(WriteFile(hdl, cmd, strlen(cmd), &nb, NULL) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WriteFile failed with error code %d.\n",
                GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    return (int) nb;
}

int my_receive(HANDLE hdl, char *dst, int dstlen)
{
    int i;
    DWORD r;
    BOOL err;
    char c = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < dstlen; err = ReadFile(hdl, &c, 1, &r, NULL))
    {
        if (err == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ReadFile failed with error code %d.\n",
                    GetLastError());
            return -1;
        }
        if (r > 0)
        {
            dst[i++] = c;
            if (c == '\n') break;
        }
    }

    if (i == dstlen)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: read destination buffer not large enough.\
                Recommended size: 256B. Your size: %dB.\n", dstlen);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        dst[i] = '\0'; /* null-terminate the string. */
    }

    return i;
}
```

And my test code:

```
HANDLE hdl = my_connect("COM4");
char *cmd = "/home\n"; /* basic command */
char reply[256];

my_send(hdl, cmd);
my_receive(hdl, reply, 256);
puts(reply);
```

Comment: Can you show the code so we can see how you are opening the serial port and reading from it?

Comment: As Ben said, this shouldn't happen.  It is possible that it is being caused by a bug in the device driver, but it is more likely to be a bug in your code.  There's not much we can do without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I added my code if you still would like to take a look. :)

Comment: This isn't your real code.  The compiler wouldn't accept `GetCommState(port_name, &dcb);` and if you did `GetCommState(hdl, &dcb);` instead, it would fail.  If you want help, at least test once with the code you're showing us.

Comment: And if the compiler IS accepting `GetCommState(port_name, &dcb);`... why have you disabled `STRICT` ?

Comment: It is my real code, and thank you for pointing that out! That's likely my problem. It compiled just fine like that, surprisingly even with all the -Wxxx and -pedantic flags. I'm using MinGW's GCC (mostly because I'm used to a Linux toolchain), so that may be why it didn't complain about that. Is STRICT a Windows compiler setting?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question about STRICT.  It's a macro that causes the Windows header files to create dummy structure types for all the different sorts of handles: HANDLE, HWND, HBRUSH, HBITMAP, etc, so that they become distinct and incompatible pointer types, preventing passing the wrong kind of handle (or another pointer altogether, like your `port_name`)  Without STRICT is effect, it's just `typedef void* HANDLE` which is an implicit conversion from any pointer, and just as dangerous as that sounds.

Comment: Wow, two and a half years later! Thanks for coming back to this question, Ben. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not completing asynchronously.  If it were, `GetLastError` would return `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.

To do synchronous I/O, open the file without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

It should not be possible for `ReadFile` to fail without a valid `GetLastError` code.  `ReadFile` only returns false when the driver sets a non-success status code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I added some source code if you'd care to look. I'd rather not do synchronous I/O, it's unnecessary for my purposes.

Comment: @EricDand: Don't use `GetCommState`.  Instead say `DCB dcb = { sizeof dcb };` to zero everything and just set the values you need.  I've never found a circumstance where "some value left over from the previous application" was a better setting than zero, for any of the obscure fields.